# Convert all elements of a collection into strings | MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In my DB, all my collection's entries have `tweet_id: number here`. I would like to map through the entire collection with one command and reformat all these numbers (`Int64`) to `string`. Is there a command to do that? Doing it manually through the web interface would be very time-consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$toString` in the aggregation pipeline in the update.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      tweet_id: {
        $toString: "$tweet_id"
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eFqzxqYnFCL)